# Screen Utils with themeData in flutter

Tags: flutter, themes

I am using screenutils in my projects. I have predefined theme in my app. I am not able to use screenutils there, it's throwing error:

> The following LateError was thrown building UncontrolledProviderScope:
> LateInitializationError: Field '_minTextAdapt@892084504' has not been
> initialized.
> }[image: code snippet]

Comment: Which version of ScreenUtils are you using ? Flutter version ?

Comment: Latest. And i solved the problem. I am using theme: lightTheme. I changed it to theme: lightTheme(). This way screenutils will be initialized first then lightTheme() method will be called. Thanks for you help.

Comment: No worries, glad you solved, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the **MaterialApp** widget through the "*child*" property of ScreenUtilInit, pass it through the "*builder*" property.

Example :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: const Size(360, 800),
      builder: (context, _) => MaterialApp(
        theme: AppThemes.getTheme(),
        initialRoute: Routes.startupView,
        onGenerateRoute: StackedRouter().onGenerateRoute,
        navigatorKey: StackedService.navigatorKey,
        navigatorObservers: [StackedService.routeObserver],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you didn't initialize `minTextAdapter`.

```
...
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ScreenUtilInit(
  designSize: const Size(360, 690),
  minTextAdapt: true, <-- THIS ONE
  splitScreenMode: true,
  builder: (context , child) {
    return MaterialApp(
    ...
);
```

If initializing it in your `main` doesn't work please let me know and I will provide more support updating my answer.

Happy coding!

Comment: It's already added there. In my Material App i have my custom theme added where i try to use screenutils and it's throwing an error.

Comment: Can you provide some code ? Maybe add your main.dart

Comment: Added code snippet. theme: lightTheme is where i am trying to use screen utils

Comment: Try removing the ScreenUtil.init(context) right after your build method. You already intialized it before your build method fires @HadiKhan

Comment: It was not there before. I was trying different solution which didn't work. Removing it is not the solution.

Comment: We are trying every option. The documentation says there are two ways implementing the Pub, did you try both of them already ? @HadiKhan

Comment: with second method i am supposed to call screenutil.init() from every screen that i am creating, that is going to be hectic. Also if screenutil device size is not set, how come my custom theme work when screenutils is not initialized